# Set predefined values in a column when an item is selected from a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am an amateur `Android` developer and I don't have any knowledge in `VBA`. If you have some good learning resources please post them too.

The scenario is like this :

I have 2 columns the first will be populated in list and the second will be the value i want to set to a cell in the same row in a different column

```
 Example 
Names     | grade

Kim       |      45

Joe       |      90
```

If I selected "Kim", 45 will be the value of the next column's cell in the same row as the list

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember Android apps are programmed in Java unless you run the NDK (which is too confusing for a beginner to mess with).  Since you asked for the solution in Excel-VBA here it is:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For x = 1 To 6
     If Range("A" + x).Value == "Kim" Then
          y = Range("B" + x).Value
     End If
Next x
```

I don't code in Visual Basic but this is the best from what I can remember of it.

Comment: My question is solely a VBA one, i think i didn't phrase it right. I am not asking for this particular 2 values I am asking if I have dropdown list.